# Story of King Prithu's request for Ten Thousand ears

Tags: ramcharitmanas

Swami Tulsidas ji mentions about King Prithu while describing gunas of bad people. He states that King Prithu had requested for ten thousand ears (likely a boon) to listen to Ishwar's greatness.

> [image]
> Doha 4, Balkanda, Shri Ramcharitmanas

Are there more details to the story, like when this happened and in what context? Who gave him the boon if at all and who was reciting gunas of Ishwar? Thank you.

Comment: This story is there in [Srimad Bhagavatam 4.20](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/4/20/). He asks Bhagavan himself for a boon. English translation is little wrong it’s preferable to read Gita Press ka Hindi version.

Comment: @Adiyarkku - You can write an answer based on SB 4.20.